# How to pass the optional arguments to a tcl proc?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to develop a tcl procedure whose 2nd argument is going to be an optional argument. If the optional argument value is -f then I just want to process that argument as it is to the body. However, if it's -h then I want to query the value of that argument also like below

```
 compare_run ARG1 -f
 compare_run ARG1 -h <val>
 compare_run ARG1 -a
```

Could you please point me a sample code to check something similar to this?

Comment: See the third paragraph of http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing optional arguments with `proc`; either you specify a default value or you use the `args` special argument. It sounds like it is the second case that you want. To get your exact pattern (or the obvious extension of it) you do a bit of processing of that list.

```
proc compare_run {firstArgument args} {
    array set options {-f 0 -a 0 -h ""} 
    while {[llength $args]} {
        # Pop the first value into $opt
        set args [lassign $args opt]
        # You'd do abbreviation processing here if you needed it: see [tcl::prefix]
        switch $opt {
            "-f" - "-a" {
                # Boolean options
                set options($opt) 1
            }
            "-h" {
                # Argumented options
                if {![llength $args]} {error "where's the value for $opt?"}
                set args [lassign $args options($opt)]
            }
            default {
                error "unknown option: $opt"
            }
        }
    }
    # Now you parsed all the options; show this (or replace with something real)
    puts "firstArgument = $firstArgument"
    parray options
}
```

People have been discussing for *years* how to do a more official version of that, but there's never been agreement. The most common thing done (because it is short and easy to write) is to just treat the args as a dictionary and merge it with the defaults:

```
proc compare_run_2 {firstArgument args} {
    array set options {-f 0 -a 0 -h ""}
    array set options $args
    # Also see dictionaries:
    #    set options [dict merge {-f 0 -a 0 -h ""} $args]
    puts "firstArgument = $firstArgument"
    parray options
}
```

But that has a slightly different calling pattern, like this:

```
compare_run_2 -f 1
```

Comment: Both of your suggestions are great and I am using the first one for now!!